# Google OR-Tools, accessing value of the variables that the solver tries. Dynamic coefficients for variables

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, or-tools, constraint-programming

I am using google or tools, to find the spend allocation for maximum revenue.  In below example, (say) `mon`, `tues` are variables for spend allocation for monday tuesday out of total alloaction.

To be short, can I try dynamic coefficient for the variable values instead of static coefficients (the coefficient depends on what value the solver tries for the variable, when choosing the optimum values of variable). When I access the variables `mon`, `tues` in a function in solver, how to get the variable values (that solver tries) instead of variable names. instead of  Details below.

I want to maximize revenue and as revenue is not constant and it depends on spend. So, as the spend allocation value (`mon`, `tues`) changes the revenue changes. Hence, instead of a static revenue value (or variable coefficient) associated with `mon` and `tues`, I wanted to get an updated value for the revenue, depending on what values of mon and tues the solver tries. Is it possible to get the values using below example of OR-Tools. I try to access the mon, tues values, assuming that they are numeric when the solver tries different values of `mon`, `tue`, in loop or the like. But the `mon` and `tues` are variables only and I get try error, when trying something like below.

Please let me know if I had to try a different framework/library instead of OR tools.

```
def get_revenue(x):   # dummy, in reality this will be tree based model
    return np.random.rand(1)*1000
    
def revenue (mon, tues):
    print("Values of Monday, Tuesday are : ", mon, tues)
    mon_revenue = get_revenue(mon)
    tues_revenue = get_revenue(tues)    
    return mon*mon_revenue + tues*tuesday_revenue

solver = pywraplp.Solver('Maximize', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
mon =  solver.NumVar(0.2, 0.8, 'monday')
tues =  solver.NumVar(0.2, 0.8, 'Tuesday')
solver.Add(mon + tues == 1)

solver.Maximize(revenue(mon,tues))
status = solver.Solve()
```

Comment: Linear Programming models need to be linear. What you are trying will make the model non-linear.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks. But, not necessarily non-linear in case the revenue increase with the spend in a linear fashion (within the spend constraints), right ?

Comment: I think this is quadratic: `revenue()` returns `random_value*MON*MON`  where `MON` is a decision variable.

Comment: no revenue returns mon*mon_revenue (mon_revenue is a scalar value)

Comment: `get_revenue(MON) = random_value*MON`  (i.e. scalar_constant*variable). So we end up with an obj term: `random_value*MON*MON`

Comment: Got it, sorry. Thanks a lot for the explanations and taking the time. Couple of questions. 
Question #1 -  You can assume that get_revenue returns a numerical value ( a scalar), though this numerical value is computed by a  function that takes 'mon' . So obj term : random_value*Mon.  Do you think my assumption is correct ? 
Or the numerical value returned from get_Revenue is some function of x (though it is a numerical value), the objective will still be quadratic ? 
Question #2, can't I use Or-tools for quadratic objective like this  (Assuming this objective is quadratic?

Comment: In an LP all coefficients need to be constant. Otherwise, it is not linear.

Comment: To insist, the model needs to be closed before solving (no call to python code after, no random objects, no variable coefficients). What you want is stochastic optimization, which is a much more complex beast. I suggest you search for an introduction to stochastic optimization.

Comment: @LaurentPerron What methods do you suggest to use for stochastic optimization. Using scipy optimize .minimize is resulting in issues (with positive directional gradients etc.). Thank you

Comment: If your problem can be solved with an LP, sddp, otherwise sampling. Stochastic is very hard to specify, use, solve unless when you are in a very restricted setting.